# JSON Parse Printing to Console but errors if called anywhere else

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, firefox, jsonparser

So I have this function which runs whenever the client gets a message from the server it is connected to through websocket:

```
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log("Data", JSON.parse(event.data)); // This line prints to the console and works as intended
  var res = JSON.parse(event.data); // This lines causes the errors
  switch (res.channel) {
    case 'exchangeRates':
      var exchangeRates = res.data;
      app.exchangeRates = exchangeRates;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

What I don't get is that this will show this in the console of my browser (I am running the latest version of firefox):

```
Data 
{…}
channel: "exchangeRates"
data: Object { btc: "14074.6", iot: "4.47305", eth: "427.009", … }
__proto__: Object { … }
app.js:43:3
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
[Learn More]
```

The object it is trying to parse does have 500 values, so it is slightly big.

Can anyone try and explain to me why the JSON.parse works when printing to console but causes an error otherwise...

Update:
So I tried running it on Chrome and I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (app.js:43)
```

The full object unparsed is the following string:

```
{"channel":"exchangeRates","data":{"btc":"14119.4","iot":"4.47606","eth":"427.173","bch":"1419.95","miota":"4.47606","xrp":"0.231809","dash":"706.628","ltc":"100.168","btg":"280.7","xmr":"280.705","ada":"0.116473","etc":"27.9304","xlm":"0.152531","xem":"0.268134","eos":"4.50441","neo":"35.0997","bcc":"364.628","lsk":"8.58936","zec":"337.898","mona":"16.5743","omg":"8.70191","qtum":"11.9674","waves":"8.38013","usdt":"1.00613","strat":"7.62121","ppt":"17.4642","hsr":"15.0566","emc2":"2.38926","ardr":"0.503933","nxt":"0.4639","bts":"0.175762","bcn":"0.00234004","ark":"4.20568","salt":"7.4472","vtc":"8.24051","rep":"30.7883","qash":"0.91154","steem":"1.27637","dcr":"49.7235","kmd":"2.93795","doge":"0.00257278","gnt":"0.336854","veri":"135.711","sc":"0.0082906","pivx":"4.71762","bnb":"2.55052","maid":"0.525271","pay":"2.24808","snt":"0.0653773","powr":"0.600372","wtc":"8.40793","knc":"1.53596","sys":"0.388583","bat":"0.204701","trx":"0.00306533","dgd":"99.3254","fct":"22.1313","btm":"1.10534","cnx":"4.2002","gbyte":"283.739","xuc":"7.21685","btcd":"134.25","xzc":"47.0386","ven":"0.574554","fun":"0.0374543","gas":"18.4407","icn":"1.57938","san":"2.55397","dgb":"0.0159688","pura":"0.854788","ae":"0.619127","gno":"129.431","rdn":"2.6627","mana":"0.0577787","rhoc":"0.708204","zrx":"0.256477","game":"1.97631","cvc":"0.352239","mtl":"6.22694","mco":"11.0955","block":"24.1746","data":"0.175062","nav":"1.89648","xvg":"0.00788486","ethos":"1.43434","gxs":"2.61426","bnt":"2.483","link":"0.286966","part":"12.848","etp":"2.66891","nxs":"1.80022","storj":"0.910689","act":"0.307483","sky":"15.2854","ubq":"2.28114","zen":"35.0199","sub":"0.379786","adx":"1.41594","xrb":"0.633468","edg":"1.02743","sngls":"0.138733","safex":"0.0377509","lkk":"0.297541","pot":"0.346827","bay":"0.0746919","ppc":"3.04434","grs":"1.08135","mnx":"24.4647","lrc":"0.249214","xcp":"26.7665","ant":"2.11018","r":"0.359665","fair":"1.24466","rcn":"0.133952","qrl":"1.24642","mer":"0.645461","req":"0.100423","mgo":"0.653578","qsp":"0.103724","yoyow":"0.297731","ftc":"0.337116","cob":"0.233737","atm":"0.0159596","tips":"0.000133817","wings":"0.638021","snm":"0.158329","aeon":"3.86596","via":"2.41473","drgn":"0.231579","mcap":"1.39211","nebl":"4.11046","rlc":"0.644786","ppp":"0.608341","vox":"0.233193","kin":"0.0000647149","kcs":"0.53713","jinn":"827.602","rise":"0.416216","rdd":"0.00162468","eng":"0.622553","ast":"0.3096","mln":"76.7965","cdt":"0.0811794","trst":"0.490039","emc":"1.08536","ioc":"2.7105","ink":"0.240771","xas":"0.471556","dct":"0.818068","cfi":"0.127176","otn":"9.48643","dmd":"16.0136","agrs":"0.964252","xwc":"0.160297","tnb":"0.034893","unity":"47.7905","sib":"2.39308","cloak":"7.36731","pepecash":"0.0533478","zsc":"0.0323658","ion":"2.02479","tnt":"0.086683","nmc":"2.47843","1st":"0.425694","bq":"0.0144683","mod":"2.06683","nlg":"0.0990707","lbc":"0.312304","gcr":"0.337744","taas":"4.19078","ok":"0.458312","plr":"0.147244","btx":"18.4111","amb":"0.228292","nlc2":"0.154277","mue":"0.303535","xaur":"0.245648","zny":"0.412465","sphr":"10.0499","dnt":"0.0510917","grid":"0.780742","ctr":"0.44982","grc":"0.0783","atb":"0.760273","cnd":"0.0204148","trig":"0.916718","leo":"0.30954","gup":"0.386337","tix":"0.716951","shift":"2.49187","xel":"0.324043","mda":"1.44015","blk":"0.365754","bbr":"2.58039","crw":"1.69675","csno":"0.393491","enj":"0.0359028","smart":"0.381232","edo":"2.48197","omni":"46.4706","nmr":"19.9809","payx":"0.376996","rby":"1.01419","avt":"4.21122","tkn":"1.05351","wct":"2.49338","sls":"24.5885","hmq":"0.151176","tx":"3.93951","amp":"0.29711","fuel":"0.0503226","wgr":"0.129652","vib":"0.14732","clam":"8.59589","icos":"39.8537","ukg":"0.172251","xnn":"0.076253","dcn":"0.0000693737","gvt":"5.88218","dpy":"0.771585","xdn":"0.00314379","plbt":"5.64138","uno":"108.087","golos":"0.170844","aur":"2.44991","ixt":"0.577987","stx":"0.482831","alis":"0.527277","rads":"5.94269","burst":"0.0110678","slr":"0.534782","dtb":"0.866601","hvn":"0.0518672","soar":"0.027216","poe":"0.00889508","evx":"1.16824","mth":"0.0884353","rpx":"0.0348584","xby":"0.0436985","oct":"0.62417","art":"0.61804","bdl":"0.103581","bsd":"1.03611","xrl":"0.209299","lmc":"0.0781097","adt":"0.0287825","vrc":"0.564047","neos":"4.76271","dlt":"0.19927","exp":"2.16424","snc":"0.158684","tcc":"0.102944","obits":"1.06301","dice":"2.38436","toa":"0.0124613","xvc":"1.0729","msp":"0.115578","prg":"0.248508","onion":"4.06891","swt":"2.01001","bco":"0.581989","b@":"1.5263","ppy":"4.0743","time":"21.5752","gam":"12.7641","ptoy":"0.218418","fldc":"0.0275909","nxc":"0.224743","tgt":"0.0156892","ift":"0.0779821","lun":"6.42298","flo":"0.104031","net":"1.37066","xto":"0.439764","enrg":"0.117068","btdx":"0.896309","bitcny":"0.134033","thc":"0.0601639","myst":"0.711079","pasc":"0.823281","pst":"0.253691","nsr":"0.00461754","drt":"0.0211859","heat":"0.406573","dbix":"7.6671","mtnc":"0.248668","poll":"1.73738","pzm":"1.05671","incnt":"0.261805","rvt":"0.456772","bitb":"0.00529677","nvc":"6.11245","blue":"0.341778","bmc":"0.379613","ric":"0.288127","oax":"0.455739","pink":"0.0305596","odn":"0.430966","eac":"0.000922463","cure":"0.445176","sbd":"2.97631","ac":"0.00903586","cag":"0.279183","seq":"0.228976","air":"0.00972768","xst":"0.365957","qau":"0.129482","bcy":"0.431767","bcpt":"0.214312","coss":"0.116432","moon":"0.0000430680","onx":"0.348273","kore":"4.69903","music":"0.0192828","nyc":"0.0000724249","hst":"0.299445","credo":"0.0167742","kick":"0.0284996","bitusd":"0.925214","iop":"4.84027","posw":"0.198881","dent":"0.000809449","dbet":"0.12932","xbc":"82.5178","xspec":"0.394376","xmy":"0.00530461","nvst":"0.539044","divx":"1.562","cat":"1.08837","plu":"9.1345","meme":"0.465214","coval":"0.00760537","qwark":"0.180259","apx":"10.7248","dyn":"3.98779","edr":"0.00839574","zrc":"2.03418","super":"0.156893","ptc":"0.0560056","aby":"0.00910712","excl":"1.64474","sxc":"0.0566603","csc":"0.182416","swift":"1.72547","synx":"0.42422","bet":"0.0419166","voise":"0.0108742","vibe":"0.0368846","cvcoin":"0.704415","put":"0.0219045","ecc":"0.00027162","gbx":"37.1838","astro":"2.04124","bis":"1.12523","snrg":"2.08004","pdc":"0.134859","tzc":"0.0816235","xc":"1.08648","phr":"0.65306","xpm":"0.289905","erc":"0.625541","drp":"0.767306","gld":"0.152452","crb":"0.375184","chc":"0.436794","trc":"0.282642","gcc":"0.0122009","la":"0.150185","trust":"0.186196","brx":"0.930394","dope":"0.0518159","bela":"0.146811","elix":"0.220522","pix":"0.0493769","html5":"0.00013581","trct":"1.21427","ecob":"0.0119566","2give":"0.0101859","pkb":"1.08906","krb":"1.06005","ntrn":"0.157953","blitz":"1.24117","brk":"0.279992","sss":"0.00309721","flixx":"0.072943","pirl":"0.996291","egc":"0.375236","unit":"0.407808","rup":"0.21873","blu":"0.00851589","btcred":"0.334042","dna":"0.131177","gb":"0.309749","pro":"0.331981","ind":"0.0981856","arn":"0.38669","ocl":"0.0963823","zcl":"2.40279","vsl":"0.128953","hush":"1.91084","cann":"0.053675","lux":"7.71958","nio":"0.062834","geo":"1.23605","cnt":"0.0555221","dovu":"0.122418","inxt":"6.47545","spr":"0.439088","dar":"0.296579","pbt":"3983.68","atms":"0.0396635","myb":"1.49361","tks":"3.42255","vrm":"2.72666","xsh":"0.00814656","crea":"0.293619","zeph":"0.0296523","dime":"0.0000068807","efl":"0.230851","start":"0.080808","real":"0.358371","bash":"0.00502977","qrk":"0.0140823","ping":"0.35278","tfl":"0.561258","mint":"0.000139233","dot":"0.0127586","mxt":"1.22064","proc":"0.0355738","huc":"0.165145","hgt":"0.0127884","ebtc":"0.177404","inn":"3.73085","hdg":"0.888512","atl":"0.248506","xmg":"0.43036","gmt":"0.0189332","vtr":"0.291992","rustbits":"0.0893892","scl":"0.18777","dft":"1.33885","kln":"4.88197","buzz":"0.000561828","hyp":"0.00269732","eqt":"0.291096","jns":"0.124341","pac":"0.0000008890","sta":"0.554767","vivo":"3.46151","flik":"0.0453539","xcn":"0.00728336","yoc":"0.0248949","hbt":"0.118605","log":"0.325944","adc":"0.00310777","btsr":"0.788992","adst":"0.215102","crave":"1.76088","cadastral":"0.08435","alt":"20.6006","pbl":"0.134159","prix":"2.02785","xp":"0.0000136375","ufo":"0.00067905","chips":"0.117883","adl":"0.0987881","pnd":"0.0000683770","zoi":"0.139984","fyp":"0.124595","xgox":"0.00354424","note":"0.0168489","mec":"0.0598096","visio":"0.0427366","pipl":"0.0254147","anc":"0.998394","wdc":"0.0179187","fcn":"0.339525","icoo":"4.505","wgo":"0.214893","ctx":"0.0341594","zeit":"0.0000559473","zeni":"0.00205877","opt":"0.0146001","ella":"0.756867","byc":"1.06665","fst":"0.0124657","lgd":"0.974114","kobo":"0.0781486","cdn":"0.0190962","life":"0.000278296","sumo":"0.744407","mbi":"0.107967","esp":"0.0000871841","ccrb":"0.506252","mag":"0.452519","hold":"0.0244518","mbrs":"0.0324332","rkc":"0.60053","dnr":"0.824814"}}
```

Turns out if I add to the line right after initialising res:

```
console.log("Res", res);
```

It will correctly print the parse JSON object, yet the parsing error still shows and breaks my code...

Comment: I'm not confident you're exactly representing all the calls to console.log in your included code.  Which line is that parse error from?  Are you sure the json is actually being passed successfully?

Comment: @DanFarrell I updated my post to hopefully make it clearer. Let me know if it still isn't clear. Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  It does help.  Are you sure line 43 is the second invocation of json.Parse?  Have you checked the json with a parser like jslint ?  Could you try console logging event before parsing?

Comment: Maybe event.data is changing?  Try logging the raw data before and after each attempt to parse it.

Comment: The JSON you pasted works, but isn't the same as what the program output.  Are you sure _that_ JSON is valid?  I agree with @david25272 that you should output event before and after each attempt.  Maybe it can only be read once?

Comment: I have tried that, and when I output it works. Regardless of where I put it, as long as I am printing it. The JSON data I posted above is the data printed in the console when I get it.